# Problem with dotstyle=+

Tags: pstricks, pstricks-add

I'm using Overleaf with LaTeX compiler. I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,preview]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](0,0)(2,2)%
\psdots[dotstyle=+,linecolor=red,dotsize=20pt](1,1)%
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

but I obtained 
[image]

Why is not the cross in the right place? How can I automatically fix it?

Comment: It works for me in Overleaf and in my machine, with either `LaTeX` or `XeLaTeX`.

Comment: I can reproduce it with overleaf. Overleaf uses extrem old files (TeXLive 2017).

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: Are yoe sure, that it works for you in overleaf?

Comment: @Herbert This is the output I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyEf3.png I think it's correct... The number look a little offset, like in OP's picture, but the cross is on top of the grid lines.

Comment: @Herbert This is the output I get: https://i.imgur.com/5Oyyckv.png

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: can you show the first three lines of the logfile?

Comment: @Herbert Sure :) `This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=xelatex 2017.7.12)  6 MAR 2019 13:40
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.` Here's the [whole log](https://pastebin.com/vq4h50n0) if you need, and here's a [link to the Overleaf file](https://www.overleaf.com/7254254156xyspcdnfwtcr). Hope it helps.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: OK! it looks like a problem with the viewer inside Firefox. If I download the pdf, then everything looks fine.

Comment: @Herbert That's curious, because I use Firefox (`65.0.1 (64-bit)`) as well...

Comment: I just tried it under macOS and it worked fine!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the output with Overleaf and running `xelatex`

[image]